# Legal meaning of "to the greatest extent possible"?

Tags: united-states, interpretation

I'm reading a policy document and it frequently uses the term *'to the greatest extent possible'*.

Is there a standard legal interpretation of this phrase in U.S. law? How might it differ from the phrase *'to the extent possible'*?

Comment: What makes you think there is legal specificity in that phrase? It's just linguistics. "To the extent possible" literally means any possible extent, not necessarily the greatest.

Comment: Since posting this found [an article](https://www.adamsdrafting.com/revisiting-to-the-extent-that/) which was helpful. The author says, *"to the extent that is appropriate when the degree to which a provision applies depends on some variable, drafters often use to the extent that when if would be more appropriate."* I'm especially interested in the situation where in the same sentence the policy uses *will* to imply an obligation.